# Can an iBeacon send users to a website?

Tags: ibeacon

I understand that iBeacons can send people to apps, and as I understand it both iOS devices and Android devices (4.3+) can run apps that detect them. I'm wondering if instead of the beacon sending you to a specific app for a store, whether it could send you to a website, using the device's default browser? Or at least, prompt to visit the website?

Apologies for my lack of knowledge in the area..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no automatic built-in method to do it.

You need an app to monitor for an iBeacon that will receive a notification when a specific iBeacon is detected.

You can use either a **3rd party app**, or the built-in **Passbook** app (on iOS).

With a **3rd party app**, after the user respond to a notification, when the app is opened it can redirect/display a web page which is related to the specific iBeacon (The URL fetched from internal data, web service, or extract the data from the device if possible).

With the built in Apple's **Passbook** app, you will need a location enabled Pass that contains the iBeacon UUID.
Users with a Pass installed, when it is detected, it will appear on the user's Lock Screen.
Then, like any other Pass, you can give the users information about the web page. But you can't redirect to a webpage automatically as with an app.
[More about Passbook here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5483)

Either way, you still need to get the PassBook's Pass or a relevant App into the users device in advance.

Comment: The 3rd party app solution is the closest option that will implement what @benpage wants to do.  To reiterate, the disadvantages are that this app must be installed, and the user must first tap on an app notificationlaunced on iBeacon detection.  Only then will the web page launch.  I do not think there is a better way.

Comment: @davidgyoung is right - this is *exactly* what I'm after - I'd want the solution to work on iOS and Android anyway, so **Passbook** is out. Anyone know of a place to get cheap programmable beacons?

Comment: You can get our RadBeacons for $25 ea if you order 10.  They are fully programmable and work well with Android. http://www.radiusnetworks.com/radbeacon/

Answer (score 5):

iBeacons do **not** send people to apps.

iBeacons are detected by iOS when apps have asked iOS to listen to specific beacons identifiers.

Once your iBeacon-compatible app receives a "beacon ranged" notification from iOS, you can do anything you want, like opening a browser to load an external website.

Answer (score 2):

Passbook can detect iBeacons if one of its installed Passes has the right iBeacon UUID programmed into its pass.json file .. This will trigger a lock-screen alert showing the right Pass and allowing you to 'swipe-to-open' ..

Now - it would be great if you could then immediately flip the Pass to its reverse-side (using the (i) button) and access any relevant website links ..

Unfortunately you can't .. for 'security reasons' all Pass reverse-side links are disabled when you swipe-to-open a Pass from a lock-screen alert. You instead need to unlock your phone, open Passbook, find the relevant App, flip-to-reverse and then you can click a website link ..

This situation is painful - you should at least be able to enter your security code (or TouchID) when you try to flip a lock-screen-opened Pass so that you can then access the reverse-side links ..

Others have already complained about this to Apple. If you agree please file a duplicate feature-request on bugreporter.apple.com .. Apple is more likely to change something if they see multiple requests ..